# VBA to Close a PDF Document from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, acrobat

I have this lovely little procedure that is supposed to either shut down the window with the Acrobat display or just one document in it. Only the design is of my own making, meaning I don't fully understand the code, but I do know that it works only partially. It will quit Adobe Acrobat in full, regardless of how many documents are displayed but it can't close just one (as the original from which it was transcribed claimed that it could and should).

```
Private Sub CloseReaderDC(Optional ByVal MailIdx As Integer)

    Dim WinId       As String
    Dim Wnd         As LongPtr
    
    If MailIdx Then
        WinId = AcrobatWindowID(Mail(MailIdx))
        Wnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, WinId)
        PostMessage Wnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, ByVal 0&
    Else
        WinId = AcrobatWindowID
        Wnd = FindWindow(WinId, vbNullString)
        SendMessage Wnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, ByVal 0&
    End If
End Sub
```

The logic is that the parameter `MailIdx` identifies a file name which is sufficient to find a top window. If no value is given the app should be shut down. This part works. The other part also works, but only if there is a single document open, in which case not the document is closed but the entire application. I believe this shutdown may be caused by Acrobat Reader itself which doesn't see a reason for staying open with no document to display. I also think that the window handle may not be found if there are several documents because `FindWindow` finds a top window only and the one I want to close would be the second one. In practice, I tried both, to close the existing before opening another one and after. In the one case the app gets shut down, in the other nothing happens.

I don't know why my tutor uses `SendMessage` in one case and `PostMessage` in the other. I also don't know if the window I'm after is a *Child Window* or how to get a handle on it if it is. Any suggestions?

### Edit 11 Jan 2021

I used the following code to test @FaneDuru's solution.

```
Private Sub Test_CloseReaderDC()

    ReDim Mail(2)
    Mail(0) = ""
    Mail(1) = "File1.PDF"
    Mail(2) = "File2.PDF"

    CloseReaderDC 1
End Sub
Private Sub CloseReaderDC(Optional ByVal MailIdx As Integer)
    ' NIC 003 ++ 10 Jan 2021

    Dim WinTitle    As String
    Dim WinCap      As String
    Dim Wnd         As LongPtr
    
    WinTitle = AcrobatWindowID
    If MailIdx Then
        WinCap = AcrobatWindowID(Mail(MailIdx))
        Wnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, WinCap)
        Debug.Print Wnd
        SendMessage Wnd, WM_CloseClick, 6038, ByVal 0&
    Else
        Wnd = FindWindow(WinTitle, vbNullString)
        Debug.Print Wnd
        SendMessage Wnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, ByVal 0&
    End If
End Sub

Function AcrobatWindowID(Optional ByVal Wn As String)
    ' NIC 003 ++ 07 Jan 2021

    Dim Fun     As Boolean
    
    Fun = CBool(Len(Wn))
    If Fun Then Wn = Wn & " - "
    AcrobatWindowID = Wn & Split("AcrobatSDIWindow,Adobe Acrobat Reader DC", ",")(Abs(Fun))
End Function
```

The code worked perfectly for both 1 or 2 files, not closing the app until called with a parameter of 0. But on second try it failed to find the window and therefore took no action.

I started Acrobat and selected the 2 previously opened files from its File>Open menu. File1 was in the first tab, File2 in the second, active. Then I attempted to delete File1 which failed. Then I called the code with 2 as parameter which closed the top file. Thereafter the code found the window for File1 and closed it.

I don't think the apparent rule is followed consistently, however. How the files were opened seems to make a difference. In my project the files are opened by hyperlink, one at a time. My above test therefore is not indicative of how FaneDuru's suggestion will work in my project but it proves that the solution works.

Comment: Is this a window that you have previously opened programmatically? If so, can you not ensure that it a) opens in a separate instance of Acrobat Reader and b) keep it referenced for when you need to close it?

Comment: What is your default Acrobat application used to open the file? I mean, is it Acrobat Pro, or Acrobat reader?

Comment: @Rich Harding Acrobat was opened by a hyperlink. I don't want another instance, and I'm not getting one, either. If I close the app each time I change the document there seems to be a problem with positioning the window if clicked "Next" in rapid succession. I want to avoid a "Wait" by keeping the Acrobat instance alive. Basically, While there is only one document it's a "Close Document", not the "Close Window" my code applies. When there is more than one my code isn't addressing the correct window.

Comment: @FaneDuru I use Acrobat Reader DC, class name `AcrobatSDIWindow`. My code finds the app's window in both versions, by either criterium, and closes it. I think it's because `FindWindow` only finds top windows. I wonder if I should try `FindWindowEx` or whether `WM_CLOSE` is the wrong parameter. I try to narrow down the field for better research. Do you know if the non-top app window (2nd PDF) is in what's called a "child window"?

Comment: What `MailIdx` variable is, in fact? In order to close the active window of an application, let us say, Acrobat Reader DC, I used a way involving finding of File menu and then, the 'Close file' button ID. And finally this one was programmatically pressed (using SendMessage)...

Comment: @Variatus I was just suggsting the approach that I would try if I'd tried the one you're currently using and finding it not to work. It's the equivalent of always creating an object reference to a new workbook/worksheet instead of just making one and then trying to find it again - but one application removed. I'm responsible for a substantial multi-application bit of VBA that is controlled from Excel, and I'd not dream of trying to do it without controlling the spawning of the other applications.

Comment: @Rich Harding Keeping the window referenced looks like a good point but my immediate problem isn't finding it but ***not*** closing it after it's found. My present solution works with 1.5 seconds delay between closing Acrobat and creating its next instance. Actually, the instance gets created promptly but I can't resize the window immediately. My preference would be to keep the app open. I can do that, too, but the command I use to close the window quits ***all*** the app's windows. Finding the handle faster won't change that.

Comment: @Variatus, hence my suggestion that you use a new instance. It'll only have the documents you want in it.

Comment: @Rich Harding Thank you. I'm trying to do away with the 1.5 seconds waiting time needed in that setup.

Comment: The Acrobat handle should be found any time. But the above code only press the `Close File` control on File menu. If no document is open, the button in discussion is grayed out, so the above code does not do anything. Which is correct...

Comment: Of course, if you use my suggested function to find the window by partial title ("Acrobat Rerader DC"). Otherwise, searching for the document name and the document not existing anymore, the Acrobat window cannot be found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say anything about my comment regarding closing the active document by programmatically pressing the File menu "Close File" control...

This way of closing does not make Acrobat application quitting. It stay open, even if only a document was open in the moment of running the code.

So, test the next code line, please. You need the Acrobat Reader DC handler and the necessary arguments, like following:

```
Const WM_CloseClick = &H111
SendMessage Wnd, WM_CloseClick, 6038, ByVal 0&
```

6038 is the 'Close File' File menu control `ID`.
I could determine it using the next function:

```
Private Function findControlID(mainWHwnd As LongPtr, ctlNo As Long) As Long
   Dim aMenu As LongPtr, sMenu As LongPtr
   
   aMenu = GetMenu(mainWHwnd): Debug.Print "Main menu = " & Hex(aMenu)
    sMenu = GetSubMenu(aMenu, 0&): Debug.Print "File menu = " & Hex(sMenu)
    mCount = GetMenuItemCount(sMenu): Debug.Print "File menu no of controls: " & mCount 'check if it is 28
     findControlID = GetMenuItemID(sMenu, ctlNo - 1) 'Menu controls are counted starting from 0
End Function
```

The above function was called in this way:

```
Sub testFindCloseControlID()
  Dim Wnd As LongPtr
   'Wnd = findWindowByPartialTitle("Adobe Acrobat Reader DC") 'you will obtain it in your way
   Debug.Print findControlID(Wnd, 15) '15 means the fiftheenth control of the File menu (0)
End Sub
```

15 has been obtained counting the horizontal controls separators, too.

In order to find "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" window handler I used the function mentioned above, but this does not matter too much. You may use your way of determining it...

Please, test the above way and send some comments

**Edited**:

In order to extract the applications menu(s) captions, I use the next declarations:

```
Option Explicit

'APIs for identify a window handler
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
             (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
'____________________________________________________

'Menu related APIs
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetMenu Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSubMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hMenu As LongPtr, ByVal nPos As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetMenuItemID Lib "user32" _
                                   (ByVal hMenu As LongPtr, ByVal nPos As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetMenuItemCount Lib "user32" (ByVal hMenu As LongPtr) As Long
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetMenuItemInfo Lib "user32" Alias "GetMenuItemInfoA" (ByVal hMenu As LongPtr, _
                                        ByVal Un As Long, ByVal b As Long, lpMenuItemInfo As MENUITEMINFO) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetMenuString Lib "user32" Alias "GetMenuStringA" (ByVal hMenu As LongPtr, _
                ByVal wIDItem As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long, ByVal wFlag As Long) As Long
'_____________________________________________________


Private Type MENUITEMINFO
    cbSize As Long
    fMask As Long
    fType As Long
    fState As Long
    wID As Long
    hSubMenu As LongPtr
    hbmpChecked As LongPtr
    hbmpUnchecked As LongPtr
    dwItemData As LongPtr
    dwTypeData As String
    cch As Long
    hbmpItem As LongPtr
End Type

Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
```

And the next functions/subs:

To find any window knowing only its partial title:

```
Sub testFindWindByPartTitle()
  Debug.Print findWindowByPartialTitle("Notepad")
End Sub

Private Function findWindowByPartialTitle(ByVal sCaption As String, Optional strSecond As String) As LongPtr
  Dim lhWndP As LongPtr
    Dim sStr As String
    findWindowByPartialTitle = CLngPtr(0)
    lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'PARENT WINDOW
    Do While lhWndP <> 0
        sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
        GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
        If Len(sStr) > 0 Then sStr = left$(sStr, Len(sStr) - 1)
        If InStr(1, sStr, sCaption) > 0 And _
                IIf(strSecond <> "", InStr(1, sStr, strSecond) > 0, 1 = 1) Then
            findWindowByPartialTitle = lhWndP
            Exit Do
        End If
        lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Loop
End Function
```

A version of extract the necessary ID by control caption, but **it works only for Notepad**:

```
Private Sub TestfindMenuItemsByCaption()
  Const NotePApp As String = "Notepad"
  Debug.Print findMenuIDByString(NotePApp, "Save") 'it does work
  Const pdfApp As String = "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"
  Debug.Print findMenuIDByString(pdfApp, "Close")  'it does not work
End Sub
Private Function findMenuIDByString(pdfApp As String, searchString As String) As Long
    Dim mainWHwnd As LongPtr, aMenu As LongPtr, mCount As Long
    Dim LookFor As Long, sMenu As LongPtr, sCount As Long
    Dim LookSub As Long, sID As Long, sString As String
    
    mainWHwnd = findWindowByPartialTitle(pdfApp)
    aMenu = GetMenu(mainWHwnd): Debug.Print "Main menu = " & Hex(aMenu)
    sMenu = GetSubMenu(aMenu, 0): Debug.Print "File menu = " & Hex(sMenu)
    sCount& = GetMenuItemCount(sMenu)
    For LookSub& = 0 To sCount& - 1
        sID& = GetMenuItemID(sMenu, LookSub&): Debug.Print "ID = " & sID: 'Stop
        sString$ = String$(100, " ")
        Call GetMenuString(sMenu, sID&, sString$, 100&, 1&) ' 1&)
        Debug.Print sString$ ': Stop
        If InStr(LCase(sString$), LCase(searchString$)) Then
            findMenuIDByString = sID
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next LookSub&
End Function
```

And a second version, unfortunately working exactly in the same way. I mean, returning the ID only for Notepad:

```
Private Sub TestfindMenuItemsByCaptionBis()
  Const NotePApp As String = "Notepad"
  Debug.Print findMenuItemIDByCaption(NotePApp, "Save")
  Const pdfApp As String = "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"
  Debug.Print findMenuItemIDByCaption(pdfApp, "Close")
End Sub
Private Function findMenuItemIDByCaption(strApp As String, strCaption As String)
  Dim appHwnd As LongPtr, hMenu As LongPtr, fMenu As LongPtr, i As Long
  Dim retval As Long, mii As MENUITEMINFO 'mii receives information about each item
  Const WM_SaveClick = &H111, MIIM_STATE = &H1, MIIM_STRING = &H40&, MIIM_ID = &H2&, MIIM_CHECKMARKS = &H8&
  Const MIIM_SUBMENU = &H4&, MIIM_TYPE = &H10, MIIM_FTYPE = &H100&, MIIM_DATA = &H20&
  
    appHwnd = findWindowByPartialTitle(strApp)
     If appHwnd = 0 Then MsgBox "No application window found...": Exit Function

       hMenu = GetMenu(appHwnd)         'application window Menu
       fMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0)     'app window 'File' Submenu

       For i = 0 To GetMenuItemCount(fMenu)
         With mii
            .cbSize = Len(mii)
            .fMask = MIIM_STATE Or MIIM_SUBMENU Or MIIM_TYPE
            .dwTypeData = space(256)
            .cch = 256
                retval = GetMenuItemInfo(fMenu, i, 1, mii) '2 = the third menu item
                Debug.Print left(.dwTypeData, .cch)
                If InStr(left(.dwTypeData, .cch), strCaption) > 0 Then
                   findMenuItemIDByCaption = GetMenuItemID(fMenu, i): Exit Function
                End If
        End With
     Next i
End Function
```

I tried all constants as I could find, but not success... If we would find a way, a subroutine could also read the recent files list and activate the needed one, if is not the active one is the necessary one.

Comment: I didn't comment because I didn't understand. Actually, this is what I think I need. Thank you for suggesting how to implement the idea. I'll work on it today.

Comment: @Variatus: Didn't it work as needed? Does it behave differently in your installation?

Comment: Thanks for asking. On first try it closed the app, but then I got side-tracked as unrelated problems cropped up in my form, and I don't know yet if the fault is from your suggestion or my implementation of it. I'll continue testing today.

Comment: I failed to get beyond closing Acrobat entirely with your code. My menu item count = 29. #16 returns 6038. I end my day trying to loop through the menu items and pick one by name. I imagine a function that can do that both for main and submenus. However, I get stuck on defining the `MENUITEMINFO` type in any way, leave alone just getting the name, and can't find a PtrSafe version of `GetMenuItemInfo` while the one I made up from the 32-bit version returns 0. Too much trouble for the end of a long day. Continue tomorrow. Can you help?

Comment: @Variatus:  Well, reading an application menus and submenus/controls name/caption is relatively easy to be done, but not for Adobe Acrobat applications... I could easily do that for some applications (Notepad, Radmin Viewer etc.), but never for Acrobat. But do you say that using my above code (with ID 6038), the Acrobat application is also closed? Or what's happening. I use Adobe Acrobat reader DC Version 2020.013.20074 - English version. What version do you use? About the way of retrieving the controls caption, i will edit the answer and show what and how I tried. Maybe together will do it...

Comment: Thanks for your input and support. With hindsight afforded by a night's sleep I now think that I proved that activating the Acrobat window doesn't change the the Z-order of documents in that window and `SetForegroundWindow` won't, either. I still didn't test the effect of your code when two PDFs are open but based on the tests I did conduct I expect it close the most recently opened one, which is the one I want to keep. Yesterday I was unable to access individual documents within the Acrobat window. However,  I'll do that overdue test next. My Reader's version is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: In a stand-alone test your code performed exactly as designed both if there was a single document or two, picking the correct document to close. This surprised me because the window ID (is the same which caused me to draw wrong conclusions from yesterday's tests). It didn't close the app. I'll added my testing code to my question along with my observations about its failures.

Comment: There's a week's work in what you have given me. I could make your idea work in a stand-alone test. I think it's now up to me to integrate it into my project. If I encounter problems on the way I shall draw your attention to new questions. For now, I have accepted your answer and wish to express my heartfelt thanks, sincerely.

Comment: @Variatus: I also make some tests and discovered that the Notepad menu has the `mii.fType = 0`, while Acrobat one has `mii.fType = 256`. So, they are of different type. It may be connected with the fact that Acrobat menu has also some bitmap pictograms on it. Or not... :) But it may be something to be deeper explored, I think.

Comment: You need to remember that you're dealing with software created by a company who have a history of going out of their way to avoid their products following windows application conventions.

Comment: @Rich Harding: All applications use windows, in order to be handled by Windows... And menus, too. It only must be a different way of externally accessing menus having bitmap pictograms. If we want improving your skills there is not a better way than trying...

Comment: I'm merely pointing out that Adobe have a history of intentionally not conforming to standard Windows shortcuts and other inbuilt OS architecture happily used "out of the box" by the vast majority of other programs.

Comment: @Rich Harding: No any shortcut is in discussion, they follow the Windows OS API totally, otherwise, their applications cannot be used. Nothing can be "out of the box" from this point of view. No time and no interest to really find a solution to the above problem, but it should exist! All the windows processes act exactly the same in terms of windows handlers and menu. The above suggested code already 'discovered' that the menu type is different from the ones where the code, **using those parameters**, works. It is only a matter of investigating, how such a menu type strings, to be extracted.

Comment: I've already said how I would solve the problem - by adopting a different approach. One can spend an awful lot of time banging one's head against brick walls trying to make things that should work work, when a couple of steps to the left or the right and the wall is no longer in front of you :)